# How to put sign in matrix

Tags: matlab

I have one matrix A = [0.9 0.2 -0.1;-0.23 0.4 0.5;-0.3 0.32 0.43];
B = [0.8 0.21 0.2;0.33 0.14 0.15;0.33 0.52 0.33];

How to put sign negative and positive from A to B?
Please someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sign` function which returns -1 for negative values and +1 for positive values:

```
B=B.*sign(A)
```